# Вывод соответствующей новости (темы).

Tags: php

Пытаюсь понять как вывести конкретную новость (тему) равную определенному id после нажатия на ссылку.

1) Краткое описание и заголовок ссылка.

```
if ($res = q("SELECT id_news,title_news, annot_news FROM news LIMIT 0,10")) {
while($pole = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
printf ("<div id='news'>
      <div id='img_news'></div>
      <div id='title_news'>
      <a href='index.php?module=news&page=full_news&id=%s'>
      <article id='title'>%s</article></a>
      </div>
      <div id='annot_news'>
      <section id='annot'>
      <span id='title_annot'>Краткое описание:</span><br/>%s</section></div>
      </div>",$pole['id_news'],$pole['title_news'],$pole['annot_news']);}}
```

2) А теперь в странице full_news как сделать получение этой же новости? Например, id_news = 10.

Как узнать то id_news,чтоб вывести определенную новость?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение:

1) Нужно было получить сам id через get-запрос и потом равнять id новости с id-запросом.

```
if ($_GET['id']) {  
  $id_news = (int)$_GET['id'];
    if ($res = q("SELECT id_news,title_news,descr_news FROM news WHERE id_news='".$id_news."' LIMIT 1")) {
while($pole = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
printf ("%s,%s",$pole['title_book'],$pole['descr_book']);
}}}
```